# Session id not same on index page only

Tags: php, session, indexing

I have a shop cart with a temporary index page indexx.php, various shop pages and a checkout page. Have same code at head of each:

```
session_start();
$custid = session_id();
```

It is all working fine with my indexx.php test page, I get a session ID, go to checkout or any shop page and I get the same session ID. But as soon as I try and go live by renaming indexx.php to index.php I get a different session ID on checkout. If I rename the file to ANYTHING at all but index it's ok! Guessing there is some different setting for the index page that is messing things up but no idea what.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The session id may still be residing on the server. Try using `session_unset();` and `session_destroy();` above `session_start();` then try it again. Something similar happened to me just last week and that did the trick.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The session is propagated by session ID in GET or POST or a cookie.  If defined by cookies, one-per-page, and there were a separate cookie with different session ID, explicitly for index.php, and then a different new cookie for any other random page, that could explain it, do you agree?

Comment: I don't know the exact science for sessions, they're so tricky. I can only speak for myself when problems arise and take matters into my own hands. However, I do know that sessions create their own cookies on the server themselves and not on the client-side, so it's much harder for me to tell without seeing the OP's full code of `index.php` @TomPace

Answer (score 0):

Without more code, it's difficult to help effectively.

When in doubt about situations similar to this, I **try another browser**. That can let me clear the cache, clear cookies, log-in/out without affecting my primary testing browser.

But, it's possibly just a matter of a cookie that is associated with a single web page.  I could envision a situation where you have one session for one page, and a separate session for *any* other page.  If you've been experimenting with sessions, then you may have different cookies.

If you try that, and it doesn't work, then you might have to look outside of PHP itself. If possible based on your hosting setup, check the web server's configuration.